# rpm spec call uname -r

Tags: rpm, specifications, uname

When I install my app, I would like to copy some files in `/lib/modules/KERNEL_VERSION/extra`.

The problem of course is that `KERNEL_VERSION` is not fixed.

I can find it by calling `"uname -r"`, but how do I do this in a rpm spec file?

Also, if there's a better method, I'm opened to ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could interpolate the result of `uname -r` into the directory (guessing here):

```
/lib/modules/`uname -r`/extra/
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question will probably leave you with symbol mismatches when trying to load kernel modules compiled for a different kernel.

To place the kernel modules at compile time, do as Delan answered:

```
%files
/lib/modules/`uname -r`/extra/*.ko
```

To place the previously compiled kernel modules in the currently running kernel's path, you will have to do something tricky in the %post section:

```
%post
cp /lib/modules/known/location/*.ko /lib/modules/`uname -r`/extra/*.ko

%postun
rm /lib/modules/... # hopefully they have not upgraded their current kernel..

%files
/lib/modules/known/location/*.ko
```

Which will install kernel modules that probably can't be loaded on the running kernel. Usually source RPMs are the solution for this exact problem.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a good idea because you should compile kernel modules on the client machine with a `%triggerin` so it survives a kernel upgrade.